# Do we need a classic-games tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I saw [this ITG question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/29207/8366) today and noticed that it was covered in tags, which isn't unusual for someone's first question ... but also that one of the tags was [classic-games](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/classic-games).

Isn't this just a variation on [old-games](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/old-games)? (See [this previous meta discussion](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1570/8366).) The questions currently having that tag don't really fit into a single category anyway: even if we had a wiki excerpt for the tag, we'd have to remove the tag from most of those questions regardless of what it turned out to be. (I personally think of "classic games" as "old-style arcade games from the early to mid '80s, like Pac-Man and Galaga ... but that's my own definition, and in the context of this site, it wouldn't be helpful: there are virtually no questions that would apply to the whole group, and those that would can easily be tagged with something more meaningful.)

Comment: +1. I also noticed the `names` tag, which is mostly used as a synonym for ITG.  The few exceptions asking about in-game names and such probably don't need that tag.  So I'd kill it as well.

Comment: Perhaps we can have a two-for-one burnination ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I agree, and in fact [classic-games](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/classic-games) is even worse then [old-games](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/old-games). The term "classic" is very subjective, and can many different things to different people. So not only does it suffer from the same issues [old-games](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/old-games) does, but it even has it's own set of unique problems.

Comment: I think both of these tags need to die in a fire. The subjectivity issues as well as the potential necessity to reclassify games as time passes makes them pretty useless.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should just tag the old/classic game with its platform for simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

We could burn the [old-games](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/old-games) and [classic-games](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/classic-games) tags and just replace them with objective tags like [pre-1980](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pre-1980) [1980s](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/1980s) [1990s](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/1990s) [2000s](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2000s).

Comment: and we already have the decade tags ... I think 70s would probably be fine, given that there are so few games prior to 1980. We certainly don't see too many Magnavox Odyssey questions here ...