# Are there best practices for asking a question about a very old game?

Tags: discussion, asking, scope

I know that there has been some [discussion](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/433/161932) on tag usage for "retro" gaming (with the apparent consensus now that there doesn't need to be a special "retro" tag), but I'm not seeing any general guidance on how to ask questions about very old games.

Suppose I want to ask a specific question about bullet clipping in [Atari Combat (1977)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combat_(Atari_2600)), which was released almost 44 years ago and isn't really that commonly played anymore. Such a question would clearly be on-topic, but would stand out as out of the ordinary. Should I just ask the question, adding (or creating) appropriate system, game, etc. tags (in other words, treat it as any other question)? Do I need to include an introduction explaining the technical and historical context of the game for the benefit of younger folks who have never seen a game with such primitive graphics? Are there any other practices, principles, or procedures I should follow when phrasing my question or deciding whether to post it at all?

Similarly, there's a question that's been simmering in my mind for a while about [Odyssey: The Compleat Apventure (1980)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odyssey:_The_Compleat_Apventure), which I haven't heard anyone talk about for over 20 years. Can I just formulate and ask the question, or do I need to step back and consider how well it fits in to Arqade's culture?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see no reason why you can't ask a question about a game that old -- after all, this site is purely about gaming questions, no matter how obscure or niche the game is.

Gaming.SE gets enough traffic that I think even if the game is super niche, you'll find someone answering it eventually, and you can just leave the question to stick around to gauge if others are looking for answers as well.  I'd also suggest finding retro gaming forums or communities and also asking there in addition to asking here to perhaps get more attention to your problem.

As an anecdote, I asked a question about a super niche Flash-based game a while back, that while it gathered very little attention and I didn't expect most to have an answer for, the developer of the game actually answered the question, which I appreciated.

Answer (score 10):

Ask your questions the same way as you could ask about recent games.

Create a tag if it's missing. You can provide all the context of the game in tag info. Make sure to use full official game name, it will help others to find your question from outside of Arqade.

If the game was remade or remastered under the same name, or if there exists some other game with the same name, and if this second game already has a tag here, you would need to distinguish your new tag somehow. It's usually enough to add a year, or you can ask here about proper naming. For example, we have history of questions like this [Prey-2017 or just Prey?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12418/144891).

Add system or hardware tags only if they matter for the question. Usually this makes sense when there are some versions differences that could be relevant for the question.