# Should a game always have its own tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

In a recent [answer](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15855/161932) to another one of my Arqade Meta questions, the answerer mentioned that I should create a tag if I find myself asking a question about a game that doesn't already have its own tag.

Is this good advice? In other words, are there any cases where a game does not deserve its own tag? For example, someone might claim that the game is too old, obscure, unpopular, etc., and the tag space should be kept clean for frequently-asked-about games.

Another way to ask the question is whether the very fact that a non-closable question has been asked about a game is "enough" to go ahead and create a tag or if more is required before the game gets its own tag.

Alternatively, are there any cases where a game tag should be *burninated* on the grounds of obscurity, age, etc.? For example, "Hey, we don't really need a Cometblaster 9000 tag. The game was only officially released in Uzbekistan and went completely out of print after 1993. It's so unpopular that there is only one question about it on our site. Let's burninate it with our Turbo Phazors and retag the question with [pre-2000-uzbek-games](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pre-2000-uzbek-games)."

Comment: I believe we have tag trimming disabled for this exact reason.  It doesn't matter if a tag has a single question in it as long as that tag is descriptive.

Comment: The only thing tag space "cleanliness" really matters for is name collisions, and that happens the most with popular games, because those are the ones that get remade or rebooted. Infrequently-used tags don't meaningfully impact other tags.

Answer (score 3):

The game name is the best way to describe a question and as you have seen to have found is exactly what we do.

I don't see a reason why more tags are bad, and just as @MBraedly pointed out we have automatic tag deletion off on this website because these are the primary purpose of tags in this community. Oftentimes, the only tag in a question is the game name and that is the only tag usually even needed.

What would we have as an alternative? [misc-game](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/misc-game)? For starters when a new game pops up lots of people who can't create tags aren't gonna use it anyway and rather use a random irrelevant tag (like already happens) so it doesn't help too much anyway, and second we've said we don't like this idea before because it basically is the use of *no tags* if we just have an "other" tag.